# Generate web service security using binary security token in ColdFusion

Tags: web-services, soap, coldfusion, wsse

I need to access the SOAP web service methods via ColdFusion CFHTTP. I can able to access the SOAP web service method. But, It's asking Wsse security header. I need to pass the wsse security header in the SOAP request. So, I searched with Google and found there are two types of security one is basic authentication and another one is binarysecuritytoken.

I need to use binarysecuritytoken. http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss-m/wss/v1.1.1/os/wss-x509TokenProfile-v1.1.1-os.html

But, I'm not sure how to do that in ColdFusion.

Could you please help me to complete this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try looking up a wsse jar and you should be able to find something. If ColdFusion can't do something natively, it can then tap into Java and get it to perform the function

Comment: @JamesAMohler Thanks a lot. I found the JAR file ( http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/w/Downloadwssecurity521jar.htm ) and also include in CF like

<cfset msg = CreateObject("Java","org.apache.ws.security.message.token.BinarySecurity")>

But, I'm not sure what I need to do.

Could you please guide me?